# Hidden value not being passed in rails app (Head first rails book)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the Head first Rails book for creating an airline ticketing system although I am using version 3.2.13 of rails.

I have a hidden field for flight_id in a partial for adding new seats to a flight. This partial is then rendered on the flights show page. But when I view the outputted html the value for flight_id I get this,

```
<input type="hidden" value="flight_id" name="seat[flight_id]" id="seat_flight_id">
```

My code in the partial is

```
<%= form_for(seat) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: :flight_id %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :baggage %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :baggage %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my models I have

Flight.rb

```
has_many :seats
```

Seats.rb

```
belongs_to :flight
```

How do I pass the flight Id from the flight_id to the hidden field?

Comment: Is `flight_id` an attribute of `seat`? If so, consider trying `seat.flight_id`.

Answer (score 1):

The flight_id is not available directly.

You can change this line

```
<%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: :flight_id %>
```

To

```
<%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: seat.flight.id %>
```

Comment: Flight Id is an attribute of seat. I've tried this code and tried seat.flight_id but still nothing.